# Minimum number of fixed points in given mapping class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $\Sigma_g$ be a connected closed orientable surface of genus $g$.

Let $f:\mathrm{MCG}(\Sigma_g)\to \mathbb{N}$ be the map sending a mapping class to the minimum possible number of fixed points of a map in the mapping class. What is known about $f$?

Comment: $f(Id_{\Sigma_g})$ is either $1$ or $0$.  For the torus its zero, for the other surfaces it is $1$ -- fixed point theory tells you there has to be a fixed point, and you can concentrate the fixed-point to be a single fixed point of index the Euler characteristic.